# Filter to Group URL on Visitors Flow

Tags: google-analytics

I have found a similar question earlier here:
[Google Analytics Visitors Flow: grouping URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718060/google-analytics-visitors-flow-grouping-urls)

However I'm confused because people suggest different way to write the Replace String, and either way I try it am not able to make it work.

So I have a ecommerce site with hundreds of different pages. The different parts of the website is:

- http://example.com/sv/ (Root)
- http://example.com/sv/category/1-name/
- http://example.com/sv/product/1-name/
- http://example.com/sv/designer-tool/1-name/
- http://example.com/sv/checkout/

When I go to the visitors flow. I want to see the amount of people that go from example Root to Category, and from Category to Product, and from Product to Designer Tool, and from Designer Tool to Checkout. However now when I have so many different pages it becomes very difficult to follow the visitors flow, because the product pages are for example not grouped together.

So instead of above. I would like to remove the 1-name/ part in the end. And only see /sv/category/, /sv/product/, /sv/designer-tool/.

In the earlier post I understand you can use an advanced filter to do this. I have set the following settings:

- Type: Search & Replace
- Field: Request URI
- Search String: ^/(category|product|designer-tool)(/\d*)(.*)
- Replace String: /$A1$A3

I guess that my search string and my replace string is wrong. Any ideas?

EDIT: I updated my filter to the following:

- Search String: ^/sv/(category|product|designer-tool)(/\d*)(.*)$
- Replace String: /sv/\1/

Still testing and unsure if it's the correct way to set it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by the Search String and the Replace String in my edit above.

So basically what I did was:

1. Create a secondary view/profile for your site. If you apply your filter to your one and only view/profile that means that you won't be able to see any detailed data about specific pages, because the filter removes/filter that.
2. Add an Advanced Filter with the following settings:

   - Type: Search & Replace
   - Field: Request URI
   - Search String: ^/sv/(category|product|designer-tool)(/\d*)(.*)$
   - Replace String: /sv/\1/
3. You need to wait 24h after creating your new profile/view before you can see any data in it.

So my confusion was regarding the Search and Replace String. The Search String is an regular expression for matching everything after your .tld. So for example http://www.example.com/sv/mypage/1-post/, the Search String will only search within /sv/mypage/1-post/.

The Replace String is what it should replace the whole Search String with. So in my case, I matched all URL's that had /sv/category/1-string/. I wanted only to keep the "category" part, so I replaced the whole string with /sv/category/ by inputting Replace String /sv/\1/

/sv/ means just what it says. \1 means that it should take the value of the first () of my Search String (In this case "category"). The ending / is just an ending slash.

All in all, it means that any URLs that looked like http://example.com/sv/category/1-string/ was changed to http://example.com/sv/category/. Meaning that I can now see data for all my categories as a group, instead of individual pages.